# Apples not properly spawning in Snake game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a Snake game that bugs out whenever i collect an apple. The apple will disappear upon collision and a new apple spawns in a new location but for some reason the first apple then respawns in its original location. Then when i collect the newly spawned second apple the first two  apples disappear and a third apple spawns in a new location, but the first and second apples then respawn in their original locations and this process continues...

Only the newest spawned apple is capable of detecting collisions with the snake and spawning new apples.

I have an `Apple` class that keeps track of its x and y coordinates and a `SnakeGame` class that is composed with an apple and snake. When an apple is collected I set the `SnakeGame.apple` property to null then i create a new `Apple` object with new x,y coordinates and set it as the new `SnakeGame.apple` object.

Any ideas to solve this problem would be appreciated!

Heres a fiddle if you wanna play with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/gabewest1/knuxsa5t/1/

Apple Class:

```
class Apple {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    this.radius = 10;
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  position(x, y) {
    if (x > -100 && y > -100) {
      this.xPos = x;
      this.yPos = y;
    } else {
      return {
        x: this.xPos,
        y: this.yPos
      };
    }
  }
}
```

SnakeGame Class:

```
class SnakeGame {
    constructor(snake) {
        this.ctx = $("#myCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
        this.canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
        this.init();

        this.frameLength = 500;
        this.apple = this.createApple();
        this.snake = snake;

        this.score = 0;
        this.gameloop();
    }

    createApple() {
        var xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.canvas.width);
        var yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.canvas.height);
        var apple = new Apple(xPos, yPos);
        return apple;
    }

    gameloop() {
        var ctx = this.ctx;

        this.snake.move();

        if (this.collision()) {
            console.log("There was a collision!");
            this.score++;
            this.increaseSnake();
            this.apple = null;
        }

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        this.snake.draw(ctx);

        if (this.apple) {
        this.apple.draw(ctx);
        } else {
            this.apple = this.createApple();
        }

        setTimeout($.proxy(this.gameloop, this), this.frameLength);
     }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you only have one this.apple.  You need an array of apples to track multiple apples.

Comment: But I only want one apple. Which is why i would think only one apple should be getting rendered to the screen instead of multiple ones. I've tried using an array to pop and push the old apple with a new one on collisions but to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `ctx.beginPath();` before creating the arc.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

The `ctx` keeps track of every arc that is created, and applies `fill` to all those shapes.

Comment: Awesome it worked! Should I in general always be using `beginPath()` before all my drawings?

Comment: Yes, you should use `beginPath` when starting a set of independent shapes. `beginPath` will discard the last shape and start anew.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes